# Bootstrap 4 Carousel on Angular 2+ Cutting when Sliding (Safari)

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the following carousel on an angular 4 app:

```css
@mixin carousel-bg() {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slide1 {
  background: url('assets/slide1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  @include carousel-bg;
}

.slide2 {
  background: url('assets/slide2.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  @include carousel-bg;
}

.slide3 {
  background: url('assets/slide3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  @include carousel-bg;
}
```

```html
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="d-block img-fluid slide1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="d-block img-fluid slide2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="d-block img-fluid slide3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That works perfectly fine on Chrome. However, on Safari, once the image has almost fully finished sliding, just before it reaches the edge, the other image disappears, causing the effect of an abrupt cut every time the sliding happens.

It's worth noting that those images are more than 4MB in size each; but I'm working on a local machine after all...

Comment: Can you host the images somewhere? This way we just see a blank page and we can not see what's happening

Comment: I can't post those images unfortunately, for copyright reasons. But I tried with any image that I download from anywhere, it does the same thing exactly :(

Comment: The images is not where the problem is, but without an example containing actual images (or colored boxes) we can not see the effect you're talking about